# Why isn't NetBeans running my new code after I change it?

Tags: java

I am on my second week of programming in my java class and NetBeans is not being friendly. Currently I am adding and multiplying three integers. The problem I have is that when I hit run the code comes back to an old line from when I first tried the project. It also gets stuck after that one line and stays on running and does not move. I already deleted all the files on my computer and deleted NetBeans app from my computer and reinstalled.

Here is a copy of my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Franky Caba
 */

public class U2A1_AddMultiplyThreeInts {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         int a, b, c, res;
         char ch;
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("Enter First Number: 10");
         a = scan.nextInt();

          System.out.print("Enter Second Number: 20");
         b = scan.nextInt();

          System.out.print("Enter Third Number: 30");
         c = scan.nextInt();

         System.out.print("Enter Operator (+,*) : ") ;
         ch = scan.next().charAt(0);

         if(ch == '+')
         {
             res = a + b + c;
             System.out.print("Result = " +res);
        }

         if (ch == '*')
         {
             res = a * b * c;
             System.out.print ("Result = " +res);   
         }


    }
}
```

And here is what I get when I hit run

run:
Place the first number: 10

After this it just stays on running

Comment: Did you try typing input? Scanner cannot read the "10" after "Enter First Number". Try typing the number 10 and pressing 'Enter'.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me figure out what I was going wrong with something else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works exactly as you made it on my machine.

I think you're mistaking what `Scanner` does. You have this code:

```
System.out.print("Enter First Number: 10");  //scanner does not read the printed '10'
a = scan.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Second Number: 20");   //scanner does not read the printed '20'
b = scan.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Third Number: 30");   //scanner does not read the printed '30'
c = scan.nextInt();
```

The reason why your code stops after the first promt: `System.out.print("Enter First Number: 10");` is because the computer is waiting for you to enter input. You must type the number 10 and press 'Enter'. Your code should then continue to the second promt: `System.out.print("Enter Second Number: 20");` and then wait for input again.

No programming language that I know will read input that you print to the screen using your code. You must enter the input while the program is running.

You should change your code to this and it may look less confusing when you run your program:

```
System.out.print("Enter First Number: ");  //no '10', but the space after the colon remains
a = scan.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Second Number: ");   //no '20', but the space after the colon remains
b = scan.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Third Number: ");   //no '30', but the space after the colon remains
c = scan.nextInt();
```

You should find when you give the computer 10, 20, 30, and * as input that your answer is 6000.

Comment: I appreciate the help! I was able to figure out some other things I needed to do to get to my finished product after getting help with this issue.